# Select multiple options from option

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, mysqli

So I have a selector which gets its information from a database.

When I select something from the selector and press: `Add to list`, it generates a table with the selected information.

[image: what it looks like after i selected one]

Now this what it should do. But now, when I select another result and press `Add to list`. It removes the old one and replaces it with the new one.
[image: what it looks like when i add a new one]

But I actually don't want it to remove the old one, but make a new row under it. So that table gets bigger. How do I do this?

**Code for selector:**

```
<!--Selector-->
<?php
    //Get name and id data from the db. In an assoc array
        $results = $database->Selector();
        echo "<form name='form' method='POST' id='selector'>";
        echo "<select name='train_name' id='train_name' multiple='multiple'>";
        // Loop trough the results and make an option of every train_name
        foreach($results as $res){
                    echo "<option value=" . $res['train_name'] . ">" . $res['train_name'] . "</option>";
            }  
        echo "</select>";
        echo "<br />" . "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='Add' value='Add to list'/>" . "</td>";
        echo "</form>";
    if(isset($_POST["train_name"])){

    //Get all data from database, in an assoc array
        $results = $database->getAllAssoc();

        //Make table headers
        ?>
        <div id="train_select_table">
        <form name="selector" method="post" action="customer_list.php?user_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']?>">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Train name</th>
                    <th>Number of bogies</th>
                    <th>Number of axles</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                    <th>More info</th>
                    <th>Check</th>
                <!--Only for admins (later!)-->
                <!--<th>XML</th>
                    <th>SQL</th>    -->
                </tr>
            <div id="looprow">
                <?php      
                    foreach($results as $res){
                    //Loop trough results, generate a tablerow every time
                ?>
                <tr>     
                    <td name="train_name"><?php echo $res['train_name']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $res['number_of_bogies']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $res['number_of_axles']?></td>
                    <td><a href="remove_from_table.php?train_id=<?php echo $res['train_id']?>">Delete</a></td>
                    <td><a href="expand_info.php?train_id=<?php echo $res['train_id']?>">More Information</a></td> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $res['train_id']?>"></td>
                                                <!--Only for admins (later!)--> 
                    <!--<td><a href="convert_to_xml.php?train_id=<?php echo $res['train_id']?>">XML</a></td>
                    <td><a href="convert_to_sql.php?train_id=<?php echo $res['train_id']?>">SQL</a></td>-->
                </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
            </div>
        </table><br />
        <input name="Add to list" type="submit" id="add_to_list" value="add_to_list">
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

**Function:**

```
function getAllAssoc() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM train_information WHERE train_name = :train_name";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":train_name", $_POST["train_name"]);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }

function selector() {
        $sql = "SELECT train_name, train_id FROM train_information";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);   
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

I understand why it keeps replacing the old row. this is because I send a new query. but I don't know how to keep the old one.

Answer (score 0):

as each time user will chose a single value while not mutiple value, so if you want to use the new value and the old value too, you should store the old value using `cookie` or `session` or hidden input in that form. It depends on you.

E.g. at the beginning, do this:

```
<?php
session_start();//make it be before your output if you want to use session or cookie
if(!$_SESSION['train_name']) $_SESSION['train_name'] = array();
if(isset($_POST["train_name"])) $_SESSION['train_name'] = array_merge ($_SESSION['train_name'], $_POST["train_name"]);
.......
//next step, inquiry with $_SESSION['train_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the name of your multiple select list from `train_name` to `train_name[]` as follows:

```
...
echo "<select name='train_name[]' id='train_name' multiple='multiple'>";
...
```

By this way your `$_POST['train_name']` will be an array passed to `bindParam`